# How to set elasticsearch index mapping as not_analysed for all the fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I want my elasticsearch index to match the exact value for all the fields. How do I map my index to "not_analysed" for all the fields.

Comment: are you using the static mapping or dynamic mapping and which language, client and version of ES u using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic_templates mapping for this. As a default, Elasticsearch is making the fields type as `text` and `index: true` like below:

```
{
  "products2": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "properties": {
          "color": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see, also it creates a keyword field as multi-field. This keyword fields indexed but not analyzed like text. if you want to drop this default behaviour. You can use below configuration for the index while creating it :

```
PUT products
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "index": false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After doing this the index will be like below :

```
{
  "products": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "strings": {
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": false
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "color": {
            "type": "keyword",
              "index": false
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "keyword",
              "index": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I don't know the case but you can use the multi-field feature as mentioned by @Kamal. Otherwise, you can not search on the not analyzed fields. Also, you can use the dynamic_templates mapping set some fields are analyzed.

Please check the documentation for more information :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html

Also, I was explained the behaviour in [this](https://medium.com/@kulekci/elasticsearch-dinamik-kal%C4%B1plar-dynamic-templates-5c9ffa8262e3) article. Sorry about that but it is Turkish. You can check the example code samples with google translate if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making use of [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) in your mapping *(which would be default behavior if you aren't creating mapping (dynamic mapping))*.

That way you can switch to *traditional search* and *exact match* searches when required.

Note that for exact matches, you would need to have [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) datatype + [`Term Query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html). Sample examples are provided in the links I've specified.

Hope it helps!